# C# экспорт в Excel

Tags: c#, vsto

Подскажите пожалуйста как в приведенном с низу коде при экспорте таблицы в Excel в документе был заголовок таблицы "Название"

```
 public void PrintDvij(DataGridView grid, string name)//Экспорт в excel машины и оборудование
 {
     xlApp = new Excel.Application();


     try
     {
         //добавляем книгу
         xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

         //делаем временно неактивным документ
         xlApp.Interactive = false;
         xlApp.EnableEvents = false;

         //выбираем лист на котором будем работать (Лист 1)
         xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.Sheets[1];
         //Название листа
         xlSheet.Name = name;

         //Выгрузка данных
         System.Data.DataTable dt = GetObor(grid);


         int collInd = 0;
         int rowInd = 0;
         string data = "";

         //называем колонки
         for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
         {
             data = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
             xlSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = data;

             //выделяем первую строку
             xlSheetRange = xlSheet.get_Range("A3:Z3", Type.Missing);

             //делаем полужирный текст и перенос слов
             xlSheetRange.WrapText = true;
             xlSheetRange.Font.Bold = true;


         }

         //заполняем строки
         for (rowInd = 0; rowInd < dt.Rows.Count; rowInd++)
         {
             for (collInd = 0; collInd < dt.Columns.Count; collInd++)
             {
                 data = dt.Rows[rowInd].ItemArray[collInd].ToString();
                 xlSheet.Cells[rowInd + 2, collInd + 1] = data;

                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDot; // внутренние вертикальные
                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDot; // внутренние горизонтальные            
                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble; // верхняя внешняя
                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble; // правая внешняя
                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble; // левая внешняя
                 xlSheet.Cells.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble; // нижняя внешняя

             }
         }

         //выбираем всю область данных
         xlSheetRange = xlSheet.UsedRange;

         //выравниваем строки и колонки по их содержимому
         xlSheetRange.Columns.AutoFit();
         xlSheetRange.Rows.AutoFit();

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
         //Показываем ексель
         xlApp.Visible = true;

         xlApp.Interactive = true;
         xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
         xlApp.UserControl = true;

         //Отсоединяемся от Excel
         releaseObject(xlSheetRange);
         releaseObject(xlSheet);
         releaseObject(xlApp);
     }

 }
```

Comment: В смысле заголовок таблицы? Имеется ввиду название листа в Excel?

Comment: Просто надо над таблицей добавить строку в которой написать любой текст

Comment: А к заголовку какие требования по форматированию? Размер, шрифт, выравнивание, положение итд.

Comment: А вы этот код самостоятельно написали? Если да, то я что-то не очень понимаю в чём трудность добавить еще одну строку сверху?

Comment: Просто как сделать шрифт жирный и размер больше,

Comment: Предлагаю подебажить ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так должно работать:

```
Excel.Range formatRange; formatRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1"); 
formatRange.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);   
formatRange.Font.Size = 16; 
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Red";
formatRange.Font.Bold = true;
```

Для соединения ячеек (если надо) используй

```
xlSheet.get_Range("A1", "Z1").Merge(false);
```